# external site in iframe doesn't work

Tags: laravel, iframe

I try to display www.google.com an iframe, but I just get an empty result.

I already searched for it, but there is no answer on this subject.
Thanks

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0;width:500px;height:500px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this as some sites (such as Google) send a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header which prevents the browser from displaying iframes that are not hosted on the same domain as your site for example.

You can see further details on this specific header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)